# Multidimensional Data Correlation

Tags: python, algorithm, grouping, data-mining

How can we corelate alerts that are **Multidimensional**?

We are trying to corelate alerts based on it's features. Is there any way to do this?

Is there any alternate way to corelate alerts that are generated based on its features?

We have explored ECLAT and FPGrowth algorithms but is there any way to use this for multidimensional association.

Comment: In general case each feature will have its own correlation, say, `Alert` correlates by `feature1` (`R = 0.9`), anticorrelate by `feature2` (`R = -0.8`) doesn't correlate by `feature3` (`R = 0.15`) etc.

Comment: Thank You for your response @DmitryBychenko but we are not trying to correlate the feature but the alert itself on the basis of its feature. What you said is right but each alert will itself contain multiple feature and we want to group together the alerts that are caused by same root cause.